# Is it possible to create alternating bool values with AutoFixture CreateMany?

Tags: .net, autofixture

I'm trying to create a list of objects that have some variance in their data.  Types such as strings etc are fine as they are random each time, however I've found that bool's are always the same value in each object within a collection generated by CreateMany().

Example class, for demonstration sake:

```
public class FooBar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsFoo { get; set; }
    public bool IsBar { get; set; }        
}

var fooBars = new Fixture().Build<FooBar>().CreateMany(5).ToList();

// Result
fooBars[0].IsFoo; // true
fooBars[1].IsFoo; // true
fooBars[2].IsFoo; // true
...
```

Can the below be achieved?

```
// Wanted result
fooBars[0].IsFoo; // true
fooBars[1].IsFoo; // false
fooBars[2].IsFoo; // true
fooBars[3].IsFoo; // false
...
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

AutoFixture *does* give you alternating booleans, but what you're experiencing here is a **resonance** effect, because you also have the `IsBar` property; for each instance of `FooBar` created, AutoFixture will alternate between `true` and `false`, and thus always set `IsFoo` to `true`, and `IsBar` to `false`.

Deterministic alternation probably isn't the best fit for this scenario. It probably would be better to randomise boolean values. One way to do that would be something like this:

```
var r = new Random();
fixture.Register<bool>(() => r.NextDouble() < 0.5);
```

Comment: Are you saying if there were three bool's on FooBar then the bool values would naturally alternate between each instance in the collection?